# Telegram: отправка ботом личного сообщения

Tags: telegram-bot

Хочу в телеграмме присылать сам себе личные сообщения, просто перейдя по url с токеном и нужными параметрами. Это возможно?
Вот получил токен и он рабочий, и сделал следующий запрос:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot142XXXXXX:AAEz_XXXXXXX-1L7RELL3Yz_XXXXXXXXXX/sendMessage?chat_id=@User_name&text=Hello+World
```

Но к сожалению в ответ приходит:

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"[Error]: Bad Request: channel not found"}
```

P.S. Пожалуйста, не пинайте если вопрос слишком глупый) Сообщения будет слать роутер))

Comment: Если я ботом не могу отправлять личное сообщение (он у меня добавлен), то как узнать id чата с ботом?

Comment: Моя ошибка была в том, что бот был привязан уже к Manybot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала создали бота.

После этого создали чат и добавили бота в него :

- заходишь к боту на страницу
- нажимаешь на верхний бар, на название
- дальше опции -> add to group
- и выбираешь любой чат

А потом уже можно скриптом получить id чата через getUpdates (история бота),
тут можно почитать https://core.telegram.org/bots/api

Answer (score 5):

Проблема вашего запроса заключалась в том, что вы, пытаясь отправить сообщение в личку, в качестве параметра **chat_id** передавали логин пользователя. Однако Bot API допускает в этом параметре только логин *канала* или id чата. Соответственно, чтобы слать сообщения в личку пользователю, вам нужно вначале узнать его id. Вы получаете id каждого пользователя, что напишет вам, в объекте User. Свой id удобно узнавать через специального бота [@ShowJsonBot](https://t.me/ShowJsonBot). Он также может показаться вам удобным и для других целей, особенно для отладки.

Вы всё равно можете слать ботом любые сообщения методом **sendMessage**, даже если к аккаунту вашего бота уже подключены всякие конструкторы для ботов вроде того же [@Manybot](https://t.me/Manybot). Это не помеха.